# Using flow as the return type of an API call

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I am into kotlin and co-routines since last 8 months, as per my understanding it is not optimal usage of flow if we use it as the return type of an api call.

e.g:

```
fun getCoutries(): Flow<List<Country>> = flow {
   emit(apiInterface.getAllCountries())
}
```

I am seeing usage of flow like these in one shot api calls, I want to know if this should be discouraged or not. Since flow is to be a stream rather than being one shot.

Comment: Sure you could probably do a `suspend fun` and get result on spot, but without without seeing entire codebase or asking original author we can only guess  Maybe they were converting rxjava observables into flows? Or keep unified result type with multi-shot API calls? Or they want to have flow operators available on spot? Or leaving space for flow alteration in the future?

Comment: Generally speaking you are correct: if we get only a single value than a suspend function makes more sense than flow. People may use flows as in your example, because they just don't know what they are doing or for a very specific reason like mentioned by @Pawel . Also note that in some cases we use flows to be notified of data updates. I believe Room database does this, although it is probably less common for API calls

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Flow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/) is an asynchronous data stream that sequentially emits values and completes normally or with an exception. One shot api call is not a data stream so using `Flow` for that is an overhead. For a single api call I would use a `suspend` function with context switching to background thread:

```
fun suspend getCountries(): List<Country> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    apiInterface.getAllCountries()
}
```

Using a `Flow` depends on a particular use case. Anyway if you need a `Flow` you can always create it out of a suspend function:

```
fun getCountriesFlow(): Flow<List<Country>> = flow {
    // make request and emit items each ten seconds
    while(true) {
        emit(getCountries())
        delay(10000)
    }
}
```

So for a single api call it is better to use a `suspend` function. From the other hand `Flow` is a type that can emit multiple values sequentially, but it doesn't prevent the `Flow` from emitting only one value, so again it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is an iterable collection with a known size.
`Flow<T>` is an iterable sequence of values that may be infinite. Imagine an `IcecubeTray<Water>` compared to `HouseholdPlumbing<Water>`. Both hold water and are well-suited for their tasks.

```
fun infiniteJoy(): Flow<String>  = flow {
    while(true) {
        emit("Joy!")
    }
}

fun processJoy(): Unit {
    infiniteJoy
    .take(10)
    .onEach { println(it) }
    .collect()
}
```

`Flow<List<Country>>` represents a potentially infinite sequence of lists of countries. `Flow<T>` where `T` is `List<String>`. On the other hand, we have `Flow<Country>` which allows sequential processing of countries, one at a time.

```
suspend fun getCountries(): List<Country> =
    apiInterface.getAllCountries()

fun getCountriesFlow(): Flow<Country> =
    getCountries().asFlow()
```

The first gives us a chance to do other work while we wait on the entire list being returned. The second allows us to process the items one by one as fast as they arrive and as fast as we can consume them.